# Cancelling a SwingWorker that is blocked by Socket.Accept()?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, swingworker

I have a `SwingWorker` that opens a `ServerSocket` and then calls `.accept()` on the server socket. Most of the time the thread is blocking on the call to `accept()`. At some point I want to cancel the thread. The issue is that the worker thread is blocked by its call to `accept()`. Is there a mechanism to "un-block" from this call and call some shutdown code instead?

Currently I am calling `mySwingWorker.cancel(true)` and listening for a property change with my `PropertychangeListener`. When it is triggered I check for the `DONE` state and then check for a `CancellationException` when trying to call `mySwingworker.get()`.

The weird part is that I can still connect to the socket that the worker opened even after the `CancellationException` is caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the ServerSocket. That will unblock the accept() with an exception.

If you want a cleaner solution, set a Boolean, connect a Socket to the listening port, and have your accept() loop check the Boolean every time it accepts a connection.

Or, set an accept() timeout, set a Boolean, and have your accept() loop check the Boolean on every timeout.

Comment: The timeout method works perfectly for what I needed, thank you!